# How to Fix ErrorException in HasAttributes.php

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need to append one more attribute by some logic. So I write `getPercentageAttribute` function into `App\User_Tax`. Code is

```
protected $appends = 'percentage';

public function getPercentageAttribute()
{
    $p = SystemParameterSP::where([
      ['serviceprovider_id', $this->user_type_id]
    ])->first();
    if($p != null){
      return $p->value1;
    }
    else{
      $d = DB::table('user_taxes_dependencies')->where('system_tax_id', $this->system_tax_id)->first();
      return $d->percentage;
    }
}
```

Then I get `User_Tax` model to pass to the blade. Code is

```
$user_taxes = User_Tax::where([
                                ['user_taxes.user_type', 3],
                                ['user_taxes.status', 1]
                            ])->get();
```

into the blade file, I need to convert this laravel variable to javascript variable.

```
var user_taxes = {!! json_encode($user_taxes) !!};
```

if I try to convert, then I get error

```
ErrorException in HasAttributes.php line 207:
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
```

I could not solve this error. Could anyone suggest any solution to solve it?

Comment: Could you add the whole stack trace of the error?

Comment: I could not convert `$user_taxes` to Array.  Can't we convert into an array which is appended?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you'll need to [serialise](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#serializing-models-and-collections) the result first:

In your template:

```
var user_taxes = '{!! $user_taxes->toJson() !!}';
```